# How can I make it so that the EF updates my ModifiedDate on save?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following using:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
```

and the following code:

```
   public override int SaveChanges() 
    {
    foreach (var stateinfo in this.ChangeTracker.Entries(DataContext)
        .Where(e => e.Entity is StateInfo && (e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State ==  EntityState.Modified))
        .Select(e => e.Entity as StateInfo))
    ) {
        stateinfo.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
       }
    return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

However this gives an error and I cannot see why.  The error message is that it says

> Error 3   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method
>   'Where' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please import `System.Linq namespace`

Comment: Thanks !   It works now. I will accept your answer in a few minutes :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since [`Enumerable.Where<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) method belongs on  `System.Linq` namespace, you need to add it top of your code. From *MSDN*;

```
Namespace:  System.Linq
Assembly:  System.Core (in System.Core.dll)
```

But.. *come on*, this is really a basic issue. You can find your solution using Google with just takes a few seconds. Please show a little more effort to solve the problems `;)`